# Perl Syntax characters "::"

Tags: perl, syntax

I can't find anywhere what the :: is for in Perl. Example:

```
$someVariable::QUERY{'someString'};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's covered in [Perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html).

The `::` is really a *namespace* identifier. In early Perl before this idea of namespace took hold, you could have variable name collisions happening in  your program:

Here's my program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

#use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

require "test2.pl";

$foo = "bar";

futz_with_foo();

say $foo;
```

I set `$foo` to *bar* and never touched it. Should print out `bar` However, when I run my program, I get:

```
$ ./test.pl
WOO WOO! I MESSED WITH FOO!
```

In `test2.pl`, I have:

```
sub futz_with_foo {
    $foo = "WOO WOO! I MESSED WITH FOO!"
}
1;
```

What happened is that both programs are using the same variable `$foo`. To get around this issue Perl gives modules the ability to have their own namespace. The original syntax was the single quote, but changed to `::` in Perl 4 (if I remember correctly). You can still use the single quote. You declare your namespace with the [package](http://perldoc.perl.org/fuctions/package.html).

The best way to understand this is to see it in action. Try the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

our $foo = 'This is the value of $foo';

say '$foo: ' . $foo;
say '$main::foo: ' . $main::foo;
say "\$main'foo: " . $main'foo;;

say "\nSwitching to package Bar";
package Bar;

our $foo = 'This is in package Bar';

say '$foo: ' . $foo;
say '$Bar::foo: ' . $Bar::foo;

say "\nSwitching to package main again";
package main;

say '$foo: ' . $foo;
```

Running this, I get:

```
$foo: This is the value of $foo
$main::foo: This is the value of $foo
$main'foo: This is the value of $foo

Switching to package Bar
$foo: This is in package Bar
$Bar::foo: This is in package Bar

Switching to package main again
$foo: This is in package Bar
```

By default, your program starts out in the main *namespace*. By the way, you'll notice that I declared `our $foo` and not `my $foo`. That's because `our` puts the variable in the Perl symbol table where *package* variables are stored. The `my` is a lexically scoped declaration, and is now preferred. A variable declared with `my` only exists in its declared scope and that can't be outside of the file its in.

Maybe this will shed some light on the error message you get when you forget to declare a variable with `my`:

```
Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name at ...
```

By default, all Perl variables are *Package* variables (that is, they're in Perl's symbol table). The `use strict` pragma forces you to either declare package variables with `our` or forces you to use the full package name of the variable. By declaring a variable with `my` (like we do 99 40/100% of the time) and by using `strict`, we force you to declare your variables when using Perl.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

These are package separators. I suspect the actual code is more like `$SomePackage::SomeHash{'SomeKey'}`. This syntax allows accessing a "package variable", in this case a hash, from some other package, or by its fully qualified name. You are probably more accustomed  to seeing something like:

```
package SomePackage; 
our %SomeHash; 
$SomeHash{'SomeKey'} # do something with $SomePackage::SomeHash{'SomeKey'} here
```

A use case is setting up some module, like say [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper), which uses these package variables to control output:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
print Dumper { c => 3, a => 1, b => 2 };
```

... though this type of usage is typically avoided by using Object Oriented style.

See also: the famous "Coping with Scoping" article by MJD: http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html

Comment: Somewhat obscure  and not recommended to use fact...you may instsead use a single quote character(') in place of the two colon characters (::) for the same purpose. (Which spawns things such as the Acme::Don't library).

Comment: @runrig, I though about mentioning that, but its HIGHLY deprecated IIRC. Don't use it. `::` is The Way (TM).

Answer (score 3):

The double-colon operator `::` is the separator used to prefix a member of a package, module, or class with the package, module, or class that the member is form (to distinguish between similarly named methods in different containers). You can visit [this page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It's not anything on its own. `SomePackage::SomeHash` as a whole is an identifier. `$someVariable::QUERY{'someString'}` refers to hash element `someString` of the hash `%someVariable::QUERY`. Hash `%someVariable::QUERY` is the full name of the hash `%QUERY` in the package `someVariable`.